# MongoDB: How to not repeat a collection

Tags: mongodb, collections, aggregate, distinct, project

**My Query:**

```
db.Customer.aggregate({$project:{"CustNum":1, "CustName":1, "_id":0}})
```

**The Result:**

```
{ "CustNum" : 101, "CustName" : "Juan Dela Cruz" }
{ "CustNum" : 103, "CustName" : "Jose Nicholas" }
{ "CustNum" : 101, "CustName" : "Juan Dela Cruz" }
{ "CustNum" : 101, "CustName" : "Juan Dela Cruz" }
{ "CustNum" : 101, "CustName" : "Maria Makiling" }
```

**My Problem:** As you can see I am supposed to have 3 names for CustName and CustNum. My output should look like this

```
{ "CustNum" : 101, "CustName" : "Juan Dela Cruz" }
{ "CustNum" : 103, "CustName" : "Jose Nicholas" }
{ "CustNum" : 101, "CustName" : "Maria Makiling" }
```

**How to achieve this?** I tried to use distinct but it only shows an error.

**First** attempt QUERY:

```
db.Customer.distinct().aggregate({$project:{"CustNum":1, "CustName":1, "_id":0}})
```

**Second** attempt QUERY:

```
 db.Customer.distinct().aggregate({$project:{"CustNum":1, "CustName":1, "_id":0}})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use group,

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$group": {
      "_id": "$CustName",
      "CustName": {
        "$first": "$CustName"
      },
      "CustNum": {
        "$first": "$CustNum"
      },
      
    }
  }
])
```

**Working [Mongo playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/X5MHSeCI3j6)**

Comment: is it necessary to put the "_id"?

Answer (score 0):

Another solution is this one:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $group: {
      _id: null,
      data: {
        $addToSet: {
          CustName: "$CustName",
          CustNum: "$CustNum"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  { $unwind: "$data" },
  { $replaceRoot: { newRoot: "$data" } }
])
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/iUPzEadpAne)